# Are there tide cycles and do they impact fishing?

Tags: new-world

I was fishing in the ocean out in New Light for quite some time.  I was standing out in the water as far as I could go without being under it.  As time went on, it seemed like the water was getting lower and lower (based on how high it was on my character after some time compared to when I started fishing), making me think the tide was going out into sea, and thus some sort of tide cycle existed.

I did begin fishing during the night where it seemed the water was deeper, and then once daytime arrived, it seemed like the water was more shallow.

Are there tide cycles in the game and do they have any impact on fishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://newworldfishingguide.com/) in its entirety is the best and most comprehensive guide I've used for fishing in New World - but in short for your question, **no, there are no impacts/bonuses** etc on fishing due to the ocean's movement.

Comment: That is an extremely detailed and lengthy guide!